# Observable<void> doesn't invoke the subscriber

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, observable

I'm struggling to get a unit test around an Observable to behave the way I expect. I'm using an Observable essentially just to notify that a process has completed. There's no async code in the loggout function yet, but there will be when I implement all the logic. I don't need the observable to return any data, I just want it to invoke the subscriber as a signal that the logout is complete.

The problem is my Unit Tests revealed the subscriber is never actually invoked. I normally work with async/await, ironically because Observables tend to give me headaches by doing stuff like this, but I'm trying to get better at the front-end, which seems to prefer Observables.

This is a new Angular 9 application that I'm scaffolding up. Unit tests are running in Jest, and I'm running them through Wallaby.

Here's my troubleshooting:

I deliberately broke the function to verify my my unit test works.

[image: Test doesn't invoke assertion]

The grey box on line 63 of my tests is Wallaby indicating that the test never executed that line. So naturally the test passed because the assertion was never checked.

If I change the observable to return a value I at least get the line to execute... sort of.

[image: Assertion invoked, but incorrect error.]

But I'm not getting getting the expected failure message from my mock. It should report "expected clearSession() to be called 1 times, was 0"

So I run Jest just to see what's going on and I get:

```
FAIL  src/app/auth/auth.service.spec.ts
● AuthService › logout › should destroy the session

1 timer(s) still in the queue.

  at node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js:621:31
  at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:386:30)
  at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:117:43)
  at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:385:36)
  at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:143:47)
```

To make things really strange... if I fix the function everything is happy! But only so long as the Observable is returning a value, even though I'm only using the Observable to notify when the process is complete. But I haven't been able to get my actual assertion to fail, it failed because of something seemingly unrelated (The timer in queue? Whatever that means).

[image: Test passes with assertion executed]

The `verify` function is from `ts-mockito` and works essentially like the `expect(someSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes()` function.

Is there some quirk about Observables that I'm missing?

Answer (score 12):

I posted this question to Reddit last night. Just got an answer there that solved this, so posting here for anyone trying to solve the same.

Change `of()` to `of(undefined)`

[image]

Comment: This saved the day!

Answer (score 0):

Change of() to of(undefined)
works for me

```
it('should call myCall', fakeAsync(() => {
    myService = TestBed.inject(MyService);
    const fakeRes: Observable<void> = of(undefined);
    spyOn(myService , 'myCall').and.callFake(() => fakeRes);
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.myMethod();
    expect(myService.myCall).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```